# How to get prev month's name from array | Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

this is the array-

```
months = [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
    ];
```

now, I want to store 3 months' names in an array- like p = ["march", "feb", "jan"]
but this code is giving p = ["march", "march", "feb"]
this fails during last 3-4 days of the month. are default days considered to be 28? Please suggest how to improve

```
        var value = 3;
        var d = new Date();
        var p = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
          var monthName = this.state.monthsarray[d.getMonth()];
          p.push(monthName);
          d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
        }
```

Comment: what is `d `and `value` here? show a bit more of the code and context of why last 3 months

Answer (score 1):

You may consider adjusting your code to handle the edge case where the current month is `January` by taking the remainder of the previous month index and adding 12.

**Updated Code:**

```
var value = 3;
var d = new Date();
var p = [];
for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
  var prevMonthIndex = (d.getMonth() - 1 + 12) % 12;
  var monthName = this.state.monthsarray[prevMonthIndex].toLowerCase();
  p.push(monthName);
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
}
```

---

**Edit**: Suggestion based on the comment

You can even consider creating a new date object in each iteration and use that to get the previous month's name.

```
var value = 3;
var d = new Date();
var p = [];
for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
  var prevMonthDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() - 1, 1);
  var prevMonthName = this.state.monthsarray[prevMonthDate.getMonth()].toLowerCase();
  p.push(prevMonthName);
  d = prevMonthDate;
}
```

Comment: this is a good suggestion. thank you.

Comment: @KanikaSingla, you can see my edited post to find based solution based on your posted code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure out why this duplicates month names but a workaround I'm currently using is-

```
for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      var monthName = this.state.monthsarray[d.getMonth()];
      debugger;
      p.push(monthName);
      var y = d.getMonth() - 1;
      d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
      if(monthName == this.state.monthsarray[d.getMonth()]){
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
      }
    }
```

Comment: The reason your code duplicates month names is that the `setMonth()` method modifies the date object in place, so when you call it again in the same iteration, it changes the value of the previously added month as well.